# git log history of all branch merges

Tags: git, logging, history

I would like to find a way to identify all merges to a branch. I can see the results I want but when the branch that the merge was from changes the merge from is missing in the merge to. Ideally I would like to see a history of this. For example I have release branch1 and I merge in fix1. I can see this with git branch --merged but when fix1 branch changes the command git branch --merged does not list fix1 again because the head has moved. How can I see this data historically?

Answer (score 1):

You can log all merges with `git log --merges`

Or if you prefer a more nice and graphical way `graph = log --oneline --graph --decorate --all --merges`

Comment: I thought so too but it does not. If I sit on my release branch and do git branch --merged if will list my fix branch the has merged in, If I go to my fix branch and change a file then go back to my release branch a git branch --merged does not list that branch anymore. am I mis understanding what git log --merges is doing? is that just giving me all the merge commit id's

Comment: @kevin when you launch git  branch --merged you see the list of branches that are currently aligned with the branch you are in, but if you change something in one of those branches then they are not "merged" anymore. The only way to know when a branch has been merged into another is trough the log.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot!

Comment: well another question if you don't mind. If I merge my dev branch into my release branch this command returns nothing, If I merge in my second dev branch it only lists the merge from the second branch not both. A bit confusing but the second dev branch did have a conflict to resolve if that matters. In any even I would like to see any merge activity and that seems to be missing?

Comment: I am starting to think what I need does not exist and that seems odd to me.

Comment: Master is my production code, from master I have two branches; a release/build branch and multiple development branches.  At this point the command git log --merges shows that merged development branch into our release branch. If the development branch changes the git log --merges does not show that merged development branch anymore because the commit has moved. What I need to see on the release branch is all the development branches that were merged in regardless if the commit changes